# Can I bind to a function of my Angular model using curly brace notation?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This HTML was binding correctly to my model:

HTML:

```
<div class="page-title">
  <h1>
     <span>@L("GoogleInsights") - {{selectedAcct.accountName}}</span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

Model:

```
// Data bindings
$scope.selectedAcct = null;
...
```

However, if the user is not logged in, that property will be null. So I created -

```
$scope.activeAccount = function () {

    if (selectedAcct == null) {
        return "[Not Logged In]";
    }
    else {
        return selectedAcct.accountName;
    }
}
```

and then attempted to bind it as -

```
<span>@L("GoogleInsights") - {{activeAccount}}</span>
<span>@L("GoogleInsights") - {{activeAccount()}}</span>
<span>@L("GoogleInsights") - {{$scope.activeAccount}}</span>
<span>@L("GoogleInsights") - {{$scope.activeAccount()}}</span>
```

But none of these is working. Here is what I see in the browser for each of these:

```
<span>@L("GoogleInsights") - {{activeAccount}}</span>
```

Google Insights -

```
<span>@L("GoogleInsights") - {{activeAccount()}}</span>
```

Google Insights - {{activeAccount()}}

```
<span>@L("GoogleInsights") - {{$scope.activeAccount}}</span>
```

Google Insights -

```
<span>@L("GoogleInsights") - {{$scope.activeAccount()}}</span>
```

Google Insights -

The only one of these which showed any 'signs of life' was

```
<span>@L("GoogleInsights") - {{activeAccount()}}</span>
```

But obviously I didn't get the functional return. And a breakpoint set in the function does not trip when the page is rendered.

First question - should I be able to bind to a *function* in this manner?

If not, then this discussion is over and thank you for your answer.

If yes, can you spot what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: You certainly can bind to a function. `{{ activeAccount() }}` is valid syntax. Have you tried debugging the function to ensure it is being called?

Comment: Should `selectedAcct` be `$scope.selectedAcct` in your function?

Comment: @FrankWitte Thank you!!! When I am inside of $scope, I need to preface every property / function reference with $scope.?

Comment: So this is the correct notation: <span>@L("GoogleInsights") - {{activeAccount()}}</span>. Once the function is corrected internally as FrankWitte pointed out, it is working.

Comment: Indeed, it's the "glue" between your view and application controller.

Comment: You do _not_ need to preface every property/function with `$scope.`, only those you want to reference from your template. If the property is injected or declared within your controller it can simply be referenced - just like everyday Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

{{ activeAccount() }} is the correct syntax but is not recommended. Everytime change detection is triggered your function is run again. Once you get it working place a console.log in the function to see how much the function is triggered. You should design your app to only run the calculation logic when required and store the result on a scope variable.

On a side note injecting $scope is not recommended, it is a legacy way of developing AngularJS. Look into controller as syntax or use components.